# Excel SUMPRODUCT - exclude header cells from formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns, one with a date and one with values, and I want to sum up all cells, where the year of the date is the desired year. My problem is, that I have headers in the table, and I don't want to manually define first and last rows to consider, but to take all rows...

This fails with `#VALUE!` error:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C:C)=2015)*(E:E))
```

This works:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C2:C1000)=2015)*(E2:E1000))
```

In `C1` and `E1` I have headers (text). They are formatted as text and in simple formulas that's enough to have them excluded from the formula, but this is not working with the `SUMPRODUCT`...

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other, slightly more readable, suggestion.

```
=SUM(IFERROR((YEAR(C:C)=2015)*E:E,0))
```

Use that as an array function (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, not just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: Good suggestion, I sadly only use array functions rarely... Still, this solution would have to be mixed mith mine though, as it does not solve the problem of excluding the first row...

Comment: I tried it and it does work well, BUT it does not ignore text cells... Therefore, I get the `#VALUE` error as well...

Comment: Perfect, now it is readable AND working. Much better than my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting it I had an idea and it works:

Solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(INDIRECT("C2:C"&(MATCH(0;E:E;-1));TRUE))=2015)*(INDIRECT("E2:E"&(MATCH(0;E:E;-1));TRUE)))
```

The match function finds the last cell with a value >= 0, for me that's working fine. Dependent on the use case, you would have to adjsut the match function...

Comment: what is "WAHR" in your formula?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to translate this word... Excel uses local function names.. WAHR is TRUE in german...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better solution?

Yes, there is.

Use tables (select your range and then: Insert - Table), and there you can write your formula like:

`=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(Table1[HeaderC])=2015)*(Table1[HeaderE]))`

Of course, instead of `HeaderC` write the real header in column C, and the same for column E.

Comment: Did not know that. I still prefer a solution where all necessary actions are done in the cell directly...